# Sitecore CSS class layout for table in rich-text editor

Tags: telerik, sitecore, css-tables, sitecore7.2

I need to define my own styling for table like we have some default table CSS class layouts as shown below.

[image: Screenshot]

although after some Google I found solution that how to define class for specific row, cell, column or main class for table but not complete styling layout like above.

Comment: Do you want to make drop-list in Layout's CSS Class field? Now, "Apply Class" is selected.

Answer (score 4):

The Telerik website shows how to get your own custom table classes into their editor. See the link below for how to create the style sheet.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/tablelayoutcssfile/defaultcs.aspx

Once you've created your style sheet you'll need to modify the EditorPage.aspx file which Sitecore uses to render the Telerik RadEditor control.

```
<site root>\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\EditorPage.aspx
```

Add the following line as a property of the `telerik:RadEditor` control.

```
TableLayoutCssFile="~/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/TableLayoutCss.css"
```

The above assumes the CSS file you created is named `TableLayoutCss.css`.

Comment: Is there a way to add this property via XML in the specified `ToolsFile`? I'd rather not modify the .aspx file if possible.

Comment: also update preview.aspx so the style is visible about of editing the rte
https://nerdythingsbydj.com/2023/03/17/sitecore-rte-table-custom-styles/